# error using tensorflow in flask app deploy to apache2

Tags: python, apache, tensorflow, mod-wsgi

here, i want to use tensorflow in flask app where the app deploy in apache2 server

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

got error like this from log apache2

```
[Tue Jun 05 14:29:00.093731 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 7112:tid 140335736346496] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Jun 05 14:29:01.225840 2018] [wsgi:warn] [pid 7234:tid 140317437794176] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.11.
[Tue Jun 05 14:29:01.225914 2018] [wsgi:warn] [pid 7234:tid 140317437794176] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.12.
[Tue Jun 05 14:29:01.227181 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 7234:tid 140317437794176] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.2g mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/2.7.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jun 05 14:29:01.227202 2018] [core:notice] [pid 7234:tid 140317437794176] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
Dlib was compiled to use SSE41 instructions, but these aren't available on your machine.
[Tue Jun 05 14:29:05.338628 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 7239:tid 140317252646656] [client 192.168.96.9:51066] Truncated or oversized response headers received from daemon process 'class': /var/www/html/classifier/class.wsgi
[Tue Jun 05 14:29:06.232545 2018] [core:notice] [pid 7234:tid 140317437794176] AH00051: child pid 7238 exit signal Illegal instruction (4), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
```

class.wsgi:

```
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, "/var/www/html/classifier/")

from index import app as application
```

any clue for the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to Apache configuration:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

See:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/application-issues.html#python-simplified-gil-state-api

Comment: already in config site-enables

<Directory /var/www/html/classifier>
                        WSGIProcessGroup class
                        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>

or wrong place ?

Comment: Have you verified it is being applied and you haven't got the directory path for ``Directory`` wrong in some way. http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html#sub-interpreter-being-used